# Safe to drive a car that have back diff leak?

Tags: oil, leak, oil-leak, differential, rear-differential

I have Range Rover Sport 2013.

The back diff have been leaking for a month maby 1-2 drops each morning when I go to my parking lot in the morning.

I have Service 17th April for the mechanics to take a look at it. Is it safe to drive it until then?

Here is a picture of the leak

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/529325631817777152/558011360156319754/image0.jpg?width=467&height=467

Answer (score 1):

I've had diffs that leaked until I got around to sorting the gasket...

But if the pinion seal is pouring the oil out then it needs to be done as soon as..

So, should be fine until the 17th but get them to sort it.

Comment: Thank you! for the answer here is a picture of the leak, is it the pinion seal?

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/529325631817777152/558011360156319754/image0.jpg?width=467&height=467

Comment: can't tell for sure - need more and better pics...

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much oil is left. A liter + of oil can make a lot of spots on the ground. I would not pull a trailer but I would guess no problem for a month. Nissan Titan trucks have Eaton rear axel which have had problems like leaking : My son's has been leaving spots for a couple years , he occasionally checks it ,maybe he has added oil.